# How to download android gradle project dependencies to custom folder?

Tags: android, gradle, android-sdk-tools

How to download android gradle project dependencies to custom folder?

I cannot save or read *.exe files in my home folder in my work enviroment under Windows (due security reason and corporate policy)

How to resolve exception thrown by gradle when I try to build or import in IDE Android project?

I tried to change Gradle user home, but it didn't help.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\{my-company-url-for-user-home}\android-sdk-windows\SDK Manager.exe (Access is denied)
    at org.rauschig.jarchivelib.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:50)
    at org.rauschig.jarchivelib.CommonsArchiver.extract(CommonsArchiver.java:83)
    at org.rauschig.jarchivelib.Archiver$extract.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkDownload.download(SdkDownload.groovy:57)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkDownload$download$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.Downloader$Real.download(Downloader.groovy:8)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.Downloader$download.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver.downloadSdk(SdkResolver.groovy:95)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver$downloadSdk$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver.resolve(SdkResolver.groovy:87)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver$resolve$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver.resolve(SdkResolver.groovy:17)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver$resolve.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy:27)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin.time(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy:45)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin$time$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin.apply(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy:26)
    at com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.SdkManagerPlugin.apply(SdkManagerPlugin.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_1nbccshuhk647b9aqa26vge5lo.run(C:\Projects\Android\core\build.gradle:1)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution while reading debug logs:

Set up ANDROID_HOME enviroment variable

```
13:18:32.382 [DEBUG] [com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver] Missing l
ocal.properties.
13:18:32.395 [DEBUG] [com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver] Missing A
NDROID_HOME.
13:18:32.406 [LIFECYCLE] [com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkResolver] Andro
id SDK not found. Downloading...
13:18:32.425 [DEBUG] [com.jakewharton.sdkmanager.internal.SdkDownload] Downloadi
ng SDK from http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23-windows.zip.
```

Answer (score 1):

To gather all the dependencies, you can just “copy” the configuration that represents the dependencies you want.

For example, to copy all the compile time and runtime dependencies you could do something like:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/output/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

you can also use `gradle.user.home` system property property  or `--gradle-user-home` command line property

Comment: I cannot complete previous step and download deps. So additional tasks to copy downloaded deps doesn't help me.

Comment: if you can't download it at all , try changing the gradle home directory using what i have included in the answer and let me know if any of it works .

Comment: I tried changing the gradle home with all 3 options, but it did't help